# update magento 2 version 2.3.5 to version 2.3.5-p2?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

how to update magento 2 version 2.3.5 for 2.3.5-p2 ? I tried the following steps but it didn't work.

composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.5 --no-update

composer update

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

And when using the command:

php bin / magento --version

it returns 2.3.5 and not version 2.3.5-p2

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to upgrade to a lower version

```
 composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.2 --no-update
```

2.3.2

Change the version string here...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.2 --no-update
```

to

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.5-p2 --no-update
```

and I think there shouldn't be a problem anymore!